# Создание многоугольника произвольной формы в Box2D v 2.2.1

Tags: box2d

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сделать тело произвольной формы (не прямоугольник) в box2d. Функция `.SetAsArray` не работает, а новый аналог я не знаю т.к. не нашел... Знает кто-нибудь функцию-аналог SetArray? Неужто придется делать форму из кусочков прямоугольников?

Comment: Неужто никто знает как делается многоугольник в box2d v2.2.1?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё, похоже нашел ответ на вопрос тут http://tigrojop.ru/files/translate/box2d/box2d-manual-2.2.0-rus.html
Вопрос снят.